# Can I say " Letting go and letting in" in one sentence without providing details?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I want to be general and say: "This movie is about letting go and letting in".
(for example:letting go of an old love,friendship and allowing a new one to come in; or anything else for that matter)
Will an average person understand the meaning, which is:the struggle of releasing the "old"emotions and allowing the "new" ones.

Comment: I think "letting go" as a phrase by itself is OK. But when I read up to "letting in", I am waiting for you to say what it is. Additional context for "letting go and letting in" would be needed to know if the reader needs more information or not.

Answer (score 3):

Although "letting go" is normally metaphorical, I struggle to read "letting in" as anything other than literal, like letting somebody into your house.

A hyphen would make the similarity more clear: "letting go - and letting in"

It would make more sense to say something like "letting go - and letting in the new" or "letting go of the old and letting in the new". ("Letting the new in" would be fine too.)